# Create a new column in an R data frame that's the last data point minus the previous

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame:

```
Button,Intensity,Acc,Intensity,RT,Time
0,30,0,0,0,77987.931
1,30,1,13.5,0,78084.57
1,30,1,15,0,78098.624
```

I want to add a column that's the delta between the two TIME counts, for example:

```
Button,Intensity,Acc,Intensity,RT,Time, DELTA
0,30,0,0,0,77987.931, 0
1,30,1,13.5,0,78084.57, 96.639
1,30,1,15,0,78098.624, 14.054
```

I'm new to R so I'm not sure where to start. Thanks!

Comment: `c(0, diff(df$Time))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lag` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
# Create example data
dt <- read.csv(text = "Button, Intensity, Acc, Intensity, RT, Time
               0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 77987.931
               1, 30, 1, 13.5, 0, 78084.57
               1, 30, 1, 15, 0, 78098.624")

# Load package
library(dplyr)

dt2 <- dt %>% 
  # Calculate the lag difference
  mutate(Delta = Time - lag(Time)) %>%
  # Replace NA with 0
  mutate(Delta = ifelse(is.na(Delta), 0, Delta))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` to do the difference by removing the first and elements, take the difference and then append 0 at the beginning

```
df1$Delta <- with(df1, c(0, Time[-1]-Time[-nrow(df1)]))
df1$Delta
#[1]  0.000 96.639 14.054
```

---

Or another option is `data.table` where we convert the 'data.frame' to `data.table` and assign (`:=` the new column based on the difference using `shift`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Delta := Time - shift(Time, fill = Time[1L])]
```